Applying cz gate in oracle for Grovers Algorithm
Theoretically say I have a 2 qubit circuit where the solution state is |11>. I was watching a video from qiskit (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0RPFWZj7Jm0) on this and in the oracle they only apply a cz gate: oracle.cz(0,1) to mark the solution state. However wouldn't this mark |11> and also mark |10> and make it not work? However, the professor ran the algorithm and it worked - why?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The CZ-gate, as a marking oracle, only marks the $|11\rangle$ state, and not the $|10\rangle$ state.
You can see this by

by its matrix representation
or by thinking about what $CZ$ means for computational basis states: It only does something when the control qubit is $|1\rangle$. In that case it applies the $Z$ gate to the controlled qubit - which in turn only has an effect if the controlled qubit is in $|1\rangle$ (remember that $Z|0\rangle = |0\rangle$). So, both qubits must be in $|1\rangle$ in order for the phase flip to happen.

